# How to enable the LinkedIn programmatic API to refresh the user token automatically

Tags: linkedin-api, refresh-token

we are developing a web app and we are using the LinkedIn APIs. We saw that **it is possible to use an API to automatically refresh the user token**, find here the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin%2Fcontext&view=li-lms-2022-07&tabs=HTTPS#refreshing-a-token).

In the documentation LinkedIn wrote that: "*Programmatic refresh tokens are available for a limited set of partners. If this feature has been enabled for your application, see Programmatic Refresh Tokens for instructions.*"

How does the process work to request this feature for our LinkedIn application?

Thank you

Comment: did you found the solution for this same ?

Comment: @Bruce_Wayne No, I also contacted LinkedIn and they replied me with this message:   *If you're contacting us with questions concerning any of the products listed under Consumer Products, you'll need to submit your question to Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/. It's important to also tag your question with the #LinkedIn hashtag so LinkedIn engineers will see them. If you're contacting us with questions concerning any of the products listed under Enterprise Products, you'll need to submit your question to: [Zendesk](https://linkedin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/)*

Comment: @Bruce_Wayne the solution I applied was to manage the renew by myself, asking the user a new permission before the expiration date.

Comment: thanks for the response, yeah I have also thought of the same solution but its kind of prompting user every two months to re-authorize.

Comment: @Bruce_Wayne yes, ugly solution, I totally agree, but unfortunately I never received a reply from LinkedIn, also trying to contact them directly.

Comment: yeah please update the answer once you get any info from them or you found any better solution. Thanks !